# C++ templates and derived classes

Tags: c++, templates, derived

I am trying to understand the following code. Derived is a derived structure from T and what does "," means and then Fallback {}

```
template <class T>
struct has_FlowTraits<T, true>
{
  struct Fallback { bool flow; };
  struct Derived : T, Fallback { };   //What does it means ?

  template<typename C>
  static char (&f(SameType<bool Fallback::*, &C::flow>*))[1];

  template<typename C>
  static char (&f(...))[2];

public:
  static bool const value = sizeof(f<Derived>(0)) == 2;
};
```

Comment: `Derived` is a `struct` which has two base classes: `T` and `Fallback`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an implementation of [Member Detector Idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Member_Detector). It uses [SFINAE](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/SFINAE) to check whether type T has got a member called `flow`.

Edit: The comma part you're asking about is [multiple inheritance](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr134.htm). Struct Derived is (publicly) inheriting from **both** T and Fallback.

Comment: -1: doesn't really answer the OP question, he has a **syntax misunderstanding**, and asks about it to be explained.

Comment: When i try to compile using aix xlc 12.1, i get the following error.  "YAMLTraits.h", line 264.20: 1540-0118 (S) A class name is expected in the base specifier.  line 264 is "struct Derived : T, Fallback { };". thanks

Comment: @user1768610 You're passing a non-class type to the template from which you can't derive.

Comment: @user1768610 Please consider accepting this answer (by clicking the checkmark) if it helped.

Answer (score 2):

It's just multiple inheritance. The following is a `Derived` that is derived from `T` (and provides no further definition):

```
struct Derived : T { };
```

And the following is a `Derived` that is derived from both `T` and `Fallback`:

```
struct Derived : T, Fallback { };
```

That is, `Derived` will inherit the members of `T` *and* the members of `Fallback`. In this case, since `Derived` is a struct, the inheritance is by default *public inheritence*.

Answer (score 1):

The comma means it derives either publicly or privately (depending on whether the `T` or `Fallback` is a struct or class) from those two classes. The comma simply includes those classes as those from which `Derive` will derive.

Answer (score 1):

It means:

inside the definition of `has_FlowTraits struct`, you also define a new `struct` which is called `Derived`.

You say that this struct `Derived` is inheriting the type T, and the type `Fallback`. ( If you look at the line before, the `struct Fallback` has just been defined).

the `{}` simply means that there are no more details of implementation. No more method or attribute definition is needed for this type to be useful.

Comment: Stephane, When i try to compile using aix xlc 12.1, i get the following error. "YAMLTraits.h", line 264.20: 1540-0118 (S) A class name is expected in the base specifier. line 264 is "struct Derived : T, Fallback { };". any idea what could be the reason ?

Comment: I suppose the compiler doesn't grasp one of the names the error being " a class name is expected in the base specifier ". Maybe you could change the code and put T and Fallback on two different lines, so as the compiler tells you clrearly what name it is angry with :-) Possibly if you gave him an `int` as the `T` parameter of the `template` and it may not accept it as a base class type... just a possibility.